# Error: "message": "Unknown path components: /photos&callback=" code: 2500"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I used the code here: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvtJ1.jpg)

But this code no longer functions and I need this code for embed the fb album in my site.
So when i search about the problem appeared this:

"error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /photos&callback=", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500

So, if anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: function fbFetch1(){
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id1 + "/photos&callback=?&limit=0";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
var html = "";
$.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
var name = "";
if (fb.name !== undefined){
var name = fb.name;}
html += "<a onclick=\"return popitup('" + fb.source + "')\"><img style='margin:5px;padding:0px;cursor:pointer;horizontal-align:middle;' src=" + fb.picture + " title=\"" + name + "\"></a>"; });
html += "";
$('.facebookfeed1').animate({opacity:1}, 500, function(){
$('.facebookfeed1').html(html);});
$('.facebookfeed1').animate({opacity:1}, 500);});};

Comment: The code in your comment doesn't match the code in the image.  There is an extra semicolon in `var url = "graph.facebook.com/"; + id1 + "/photos&callback=?&limit=0";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `<ID>/photos&callback=....`

it should be `<ID>/photos?callback=...`

The '?' character should mark the start of the query string parameters, not a '&'