# Facebook Graph explorer: Unknown path components

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook Graph Api
so I decide to start with the explorer

I get access token with photos permission

I insert this url first:

```
me/albums
```

And I get this result:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "created_time": "2010-09-05T12:04:01+0000",
  "name": "Profile Pictures",
  "id": "1587403170821"
},
{
  "created_time": "2015-10-09T14:24:32+0000",
  "name": "Mobile Uploads",
  "id": "10207728693601171"
},
{
  "created_time": "2015-09-30T13:00:27+0000",
  "name": "Cover Photos",
  "id": "10207681207694053"
},
{
  "created_time": "2008-08-28T15:16:46+0000",
  "name": "כללי",
  "id": "1020707883793"
},
{
  "created_time": "2008-08-26T16:26:25+0000",
  "name": "דן",
  "id": "1019996386006"
},
{
  "created_time": "2008-08-06T13:36:47+0000",
  "name": "Army",
  "id": "1009862332661"
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "before": "MTU4NzQwMzE3MDgyMQZDZD",
  "after": "MTAwOTg2MjMzMjY2MQZDZD"
}
}
}
```

So I try to achive the pictures in some album, so I did like described in [Facebook Api reference, about how to get photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album/photos) :

```
v2.2/1587403170821/photos
```

But I get this error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unknown path components: /1587403170821/photos",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500,
"fbtrace_id": "AMeqGuPpuiE"
}
}
```

I did a search and I found this ([OAuthException 2500 (Unknown path components) when trying to register Achievement in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294449/oauthexception-2500-unknown-path-components-when-trying-to-register-achievemen)) And this ([Error: "message": "Unknown path components: /photos&callback=" code: 2500"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485537/error-message-unknown-path-components-photoscallback-code-2500)) questions
But it's not helped me because they had a mistake with the url in that they replaced & instead ?

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I figure this out

The problem was that I mentioned the graph api version in the "command line"

But I didn't notice that it's already there

thanks for all

Comment: I'm getting same error on several graph invocations. What do you mean by "in the command line"?

Comment: Bit late to the party, but he means he added "v2.2" as a part of the request

Comment: Thank you. I also removed the 15.0/ from the url in exchanging for a long live token and it worked.